# Mapping objects/assets along polygon line using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, linear-referencing, railroad

I am working with an open rail data set which is imported to my ArcGIS Pro project. The rail data is loaded to ArcGIS as a shapefile and includes kilometer notation for a specific rail segment. The km notation is included for every 0.1 km.

I want to add new object/assets but I only have the km notation as an input and need to align them along the curve rail track as visually shown below.

[image]

Could someone guide me how to map the new objects?

Comment: Could you provide a sketch or an example? Right now I don't really understand, what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is linear referencing.

Comment: Hi @Erik. Please see updated post with a sketch explaining the problem. Hope it clarifies the question. 

Essentially I need to map new objects along the rail segment. However, I only have the km. notation as an input.

Comment: What kind of objects/assets are you creating? Points, lines, polygons? How are they placed in relation to the railways? On top of it, parallel, perpendicular?

Comment: Have a look at this : http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm and this : https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/an-overview-of-the-linear-referencing-toolbox.htm; it should solve your problem. If you still have difficulties update your question with the specific step that pose problem

Comment: The objects are points and need to be placed on top of the rail. Although, specific objects are categorized as a line with a km_start and and km_end.

Comment: It sounds like you have both point events and linear events to display along your linear features.